# How to create user-friendly URL in MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an MVC project. My requirement is I need to show user-friendly URL in the browser.

Here is my mvc cshtml code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AppointmentType", "Appointment", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "formAppointmentType", @class = "", ignoreThisBit = "Test-Appointment" }))
{
    <div class="container">
</div>
}
```

My routeconfig file code

```
 routes.MapRoute("Resource", "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{ignoreThisBit}", new { controller = "Appointment", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                                                                                            ignoreThisBit = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
            );
```

Also I have done changes in webapiconfig

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}/{ignoreThisBit}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, ignoreThisBit = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

After trying in both the places I see my URL showing like `http://localhost:8080/AppointmentType` only

I would like to show Test-Appointment. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want http://localhost:8080/AppointmentType/Test-Appointment, try without {id} in your routeconfig file code :

```
routes.MapRoute("Resource", "{controller}/{action}/{ignoreThisBit}", new { controller = "Appointment", action = "Index", ignoreThisBit = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a route with the explicit URL `/AppointmentType`

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Resource", 
    url: "AppointmentType", 
    defaults: new { controller = "Appointment", action = "AppointmentType" }
```

and place it *before* your default route.

Answer (score 0):

You can install nuget package - "Lowercase Dashed Route" from NuGet Package Manager. To install Lowercase Dashed Route, run the following command in the Package Manager Console : `PM> Install-Package LowercaseDashedRoute`

For more detail & sample source code : https://www.nuget.org/packages/LowercaseDashedRoute/

https://github.com/AtaS/lowercase-dashed-route